# SQL query / database table design exclude results from previous run

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a HTTP Request that gets data from a website and then inserts it into a table. After this insert, I then run a query on that table. The table looks as like below.

```
|post_title   | post_image| post url | post_price |     script_run       |
|'cool title' | 'im'      | 'url to' | '100'      |'29-12-2020 12:00:00' |
|'other'      | 'im2'     | 'url'    | 'price'    |'29-12-2020 12:30:00' |
|'cool title' | 'im'      | 'url to' | '100'      |'29-12-2020 12:30:00' |
```

What I want to do with my query is select all new results, but ignore results that have previously been inserted to the table. e.g. From the table above, my query should only return the second record, but not the third or the first, because the third was previously found with the first record.

I have this query below, but it seems to keep returning all the same results. I'm not sure what is wrong with my query, but am also wondering if there is a better way to write this query and/or design the database table?

```
        SELECT
            post_title, post_image, post_url, post_price, script_run
        FROM
            table
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
        table AS dr
        WHERE
            table.post_title = dr.post_title
        AND
            table.post_image = dr.post_image
        AND
            table.post_url = dr.post_url
        AND
            table.post_price = dr.post_price
        AND
            table.script_run != dr.script_run)
```

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: This one is postgres

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the logic, you just need to change that condition:

```
AND table.script_run != dr.script_run
```

To:

```
AND table.script_run < dr.script_run
```

This filters out rows for which an another row exists for the same title / image / url / price and a later `script_run`.

Note that you can implement pretty much the same logic with `row_number()`, if your database supports it:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(
             partition by post_title, post_image, post_url, post_price 
             order by script_run desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB! This second query works fairly well for postgres, but it doesn't filter out duplicate results. It will limit duplicates to only one row, but I want to exclude duplicates all together.

Comment: @says. I don't get your point. The second query guarantees one line per `(post_title, post_image, post_url, post_price)` - which is how I understood your question.

Comment: Edited my post to clarify. Query should only return the second result and not the third or the first. The query would return the first result the first time it's found, but subsequent times both records are ignored, because we've already been notified about it.